# PDF: How to change/decode stream into text?

Tags: pdf, fonts

The document contains only Text no images the relveant portions of the PDF are as under:

```
 trailer
 <</Root 1 0 R>>

1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Kids[4 0 R]/Count 1/Rotate 0/ITXT(5.0.6)>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Type/Page
  /MediaBox[0 0 612 1008]
  /Rotate 0
  /Parent 3 0 R
  /Resources<<
      /ProcSet[/PDF/Text]
      /ExtGState 12 0 R
      /Font 13 0 R>>
  /Contents 5 0 R
  /Annots[24 0 R]>>
 endobj

 12 0 obj
 <</R7 7 0 R>>
 endobj

 7 0 obj
<</Type/ExtGState /OPM 1>>
endobj

13 0 obj
<</R8 8 0 R
  /R10 10 0 R>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<</BaseFont /LRSXWR+TimesNewRoman
  /FontDescriptor 9 0 R
  /Type/Font
  /FirstChar 1
  /LastChar 41
  /Widths[ 
       333 722 250 611 722 611 722 667 722 722 667 556 556 389 
       722 667 722 722 500 333 444 389 500 278 278 500 333 500 
       444 500 278 250 889 250 500 500 444 500 278 778 500]
   /Encoding 16 0 R
   /Subtype/TrueType>>
   endobj

16 0 obj
<</Type/Encoding
  /BaseEncoding/WinAnsiEncoding
  /Differences[
            1/I/N/space/T/H/E/G/C/O/U/R/F/P/J/A/B
            /D/Y/asterisk/r/e/s/n/t/colon/o/f/h/a/p/l/period
            /M/comma/d/v/c/two/i/m/u]
  >>
  endobj
```

The above information  is provided for requirements purposes, the content object which I want to decoded as:

```
  5 0 obj 
  <</Length 5950>>
  stream
  q 0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0 cm
  /R7 gs
  0 0 0 RG
  0 0 0 rg
  q
  8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm BT
  /R8 14.0388 Tf
  0.997231 0 0 1 90.1533 922.927 Tm
   [
    (SOH)-0.762768(STX)10.3078(ETX)10.019(EOT)10.888
    (ENQ)-6.34593(ACK)10.888(ETX)-7.12126(ENQ)2.22552
    (SOH)7.32006(BEL)-6.34489(ENQ)10.797(ETX)-7.1223
    (BS)7.04592(    )-6.34489(\n)10.797(VT)49.899
    (EOT)28.0288(ETX)-7.12126(  )2.22552(FF)-0.944827
    (ETX)10.0196(\r)-0.945874(\n)-5.8573(STX)10.3083
    (SQ)-13.6649(SI)10.798(DLE)-10.097(ETX)52.8727
    (SI)11.2835(STX)-6.83247(DC1)2.22657(ETX)10.0175
    (ENQ)-6.34489(SI)10.798(VT)49.8969(DC2)105.076
    (SI)11.2856(STX)-6.83457(SI)53.6511(ETX)61.442
    (SI)105.076(EOT)28.0288(ETX)-7.12335(BS)-1.52554
    (ENQ)2.22657(SI)11.2835(STX)-6.83247(DC1)10.798
    (SOH)-9.82286(BEL)2.22657(SI)
   ]TJ
   412.949 0 Td
   [(VT)-1.52763(ENQ)722.166]TJ
   .......
   .......
```

Comment: The `(SOH)` (for example) does not literally appear in the PDF, right? That is to say, I'm guessing that it is the result of translating a byte with value 1 to something "readable" (which might also have been `ctl-A`). Because otherwise, I'd expect the PDF processor to render the three characters corresponding to font indices `S`, `O` and `H` (which don't exist in that font, afaics).

Answer (score 1):

Decoding of PDF stream into text is not very simple, because you don't have anything like text there.
You have series of glyhps with very vairable meaning. In your case, you use font 13 0, that consist of 41 characters of /LRSXWR+TimesNewRoman with changes defined in obj 16 0, that has explanations of meanings of glyphs. You must have some translation table from "space" to " " (I'm quite surprised, that there is a glyph for space in your case). This may not be so simple in other cases. I've seen many times, that there was an embeded font with glyphs sorted by usage and there was no other than visual evidence, what which glyph may represent.

Are you sure you want to read the text from pdf files?

Comment: yes I am sure to do so.. you means that I have to decode font first and font changes then create some table to do so.. can you give some steps example to do these things

Comment: the question is, how variable documents will you need to process?
Are all going to be the same from the same source, or of any form of PDF format? I don't think it may make sense to implement the whole functionality of other PDF reading programs.

Comment: For my project meed to extract text from these type of pdf file and the volume of pdf is huge and thus required. Kindly suggest the way to decode stream

Comment: This is a good answer to a bad question. I see that the file of which you copy/pasted some snippets was created using iText. Why don't you use iText to extract the text?